# How to wrap the center content and make it take the remaining width of the div

Tags: html, css

I have an `<a>` tag, which has two `span` tags floated, left and right and content in the center. How do I make the content wrap itself to the center? The content should take the remaining width after floating the span tags and their widths. **Note:** : I cannot add a span container for the text.

**HTML:**

```
<a class="container">
    <span class="right"></span>
    hello how are you
    <span class="left"></span>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid;
    display:block;
}
.left {
    width:50px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
}
.right {
    height:200px;
    width:100px;
    background:blue;
    float:right;
}
```

[DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/A8zLY/4280/)

Comment: Can you put those left and right elements to :before and :after?

Comment: You mean like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.left {
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
.right {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<a class="container">
  <span class="right"></span>
  hello how are you
  <span class="left"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange your HTML, first the floating elements, then the text:

```css
.container {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid;
    display:block;


}
.left {
    width:50px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;

    float:left;
}
.right {
    height:200px;
    width:100px;
    background:blue;
    float:right;

}
```

```html
<a class="container">
    <span class="right"></span>
    <span class="left"></span>
    hello how are you
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the span left came after the text, so the span is displayed under the text. Try with this html code:

```
<a class="container">
  <span class="right"></span>
  <span class="left"></span>
  hello how are you
</a>
```